# set data source independent name of column in datagridview

Tags: datagridview, vb.net-2010

i  am facing a problem..That is when i retrieves a data form data source and stored display into datagridview than the datagirdview show me the column names that are of a database column name but i don't want to show that names i want a static names how can i set that names in VS 2010.

That is i want to set meaningful names of columns that help to identify what the column is represents.
Because i try this..that is i add columns from collection property of datagridview and they are display as well but when i fired a query they are overwrites by database column name.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you are currently using the following query/stored proc etc

SELECT customer_id, first_name, last_name FROM EMPLOYEE
The datagridview will show you the column names as customer_id, first_name, last_name.

To Fix this change your query to 
SELECT customer_id AS [Customer ID], first_name AS [First Name], last_name AS [Last Name]
FROM EMPLOYEE

and now the datagridview will show you your custom column names in the header.